# Visual Studio shortcut to next error in current file?

Tags: visual-studio

Any change somebody knows about a shortcut to go to the **next error** in current **file** in Visual Studio (not in VSCode)?

I know about <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> but that is just to go to the next error in the error list

Comment: This is atm not possible see https://twitter.com/VisualStudio/status/1044989842185162754 Hopefully some day

Answer (score 7):

Sort the error list by file then ctrl + shift + F12 will take you through the errors in the file.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2022, you can go to the next issue in the current file by pressing Alt-PgDn, or the previous issue by pressing Alt-PgUp. (An "issue" is an error or warning.)